# Drools Event Expiry Issue

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

we are currently using drools 5.1 version.we would like to expire events after sometime.we are trying with the following approach.

```
declare Abc
    @role( event )
    @expires( 300s )
end
```

and we are using accumulate function inside our rules.And observed that the instances are not getting retracted(expired) from working memory.I am always getting same factcount.

Are there any pointers to expire the events after sometime.

we have tried 5.3 and observed the expiry is not working as expected in case CEP and rules with accumulate function.

Please provide pointers to resolve the issue.